# wine tells me to install .NET and mono gives error "File does not contain a valid CIL image."

Tags: mono, wine

i want to run [hunterpie.exe](https://github.com/Haato3o/HunterPie-v2) . I've test wine (i've installed wine-mono) which tells me :

```
A fatal error occurred. The required library hostfxr.dll could not be found.
If this is a self-contained application, that library should exist in [Z:\home\osafaimal\.local\share\Steam\steamapps\common\MonsterHunterRise\HunterPie\].
If this is a framework-dependent application, install the runtime in the global location [C:\Program Files\dotnet] or use the DOTNET_ROOT environment variable to specify the runtime location or register the runtime location in [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\InstallLocation].

The .NET runtime can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=x64&rid=win7-x64&apphost_version=5.0.1
002c:err:eventlog:ReportEventW L"Description: A .NET application failed.\nApplication: HunterPie.exe\nPath: Z:\\home\\osafaimal\\.local\\share\\Steam\\steamapps\\common\\MonsterHunterRise\\HunterPie\\HunterPie.exe\nMessage: A fatal error occurred. The required library hostfxr.dll could not be found.\nIf this is a self-co"...
```

i've test to install .NET on my computer (Ubuntu 21.10 x86_64), Same error.
i've test to run with mono and it gives:

```
Cannot open assembly 'HunterPie.exe': File does not contain a valid CIL image.
```

Can someone explains what I should to do?

Comment: It is a .NET 5 application exclusively for Windows, so you should run it on Windows.

Comment: no way to run it on linux?